# dotnet watch --no-dependencies

Tags: .net, dotnet-cli

I would like to use dotnet watch on my project, but without taking care about referenced dependencies... There is flag for this in dotnet **build** (not watch) command.

How do I pass `--no-dependencies` to build using dotnet watch?

Otherwise, when running `dotnet watch --no-dependencies` it shows this error:

```
Could not execute because the specified command or file was not found.
Possible reasons for this include:
  
You misspelled a built-in dotnet command.
You intended to execute a .NET program, but dotnet---no-dependencies does not exist.
You intended to run a global tool, but a dotnet-prefixed executable with this name could not be found on the PATH.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must pass the options as follows:

`dotnet watch run options`

In your example, it should be like this

`dotnet watch run --no-dependencies`

more info : [dotnet-watch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-watch#arguments)

Comment: Well, . `dotnet watch --no-dependencies run` is what I have tried. I misunderstood the passing parameters.. Thanks..

Comment: you're welcome, sometimes we don't consider small points that cause problems